# Use pipe in an input attribute

Tags: angular

I'm using an UI framework : SmartAdmin

This provide an internationalization feature with `i18n`

I'm trying to use it this Boostrap Validation Module.

If I put this, it's working :

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" data-bv-notempty="true" 
 data-bv-notempty-message="The first name is required and cannot be empty"
 data-bv-stringlength-max="50" data-bv-stringlength-message="The first name must be less than 50 characters long"/>
```

But I I try to use a pipe :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" data-bv-notempty="true" 
data-bv-notempty-message="{{'The first name is required and cannot be empty' | i18n}}"
data-bv-stringlength-max="50" data-bv-stringlength-message="The first name must be less than 50 characters long" />
```

I get this error :

> Can't bind to 'data-bv-notempty-message' since it isn't a known
>   property of 'input'. ("ut type="text" class="form-control"
>   name="firstname" data-bv-notempty="true" 
>                         [ERROR ->][data-bv-notempty-message]="'The first name is required' | i18n"
>                           data-bv-stri"): ng:///UserModule/UserAccountComponent.html@66:22

Question : How can use pipe in an input attribut?

EDIT : Add code pipe :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {I18nService} from "./i18n.service";

@Pipe({
  name: 'i18n',
  pure: false
})
export class I18nPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(public i18nService: I18nService){}

  transform(phrase: any, args?: any): any {
    //console.log(phrase)
    return this.i18nService.getTranslation(phrase);
  }

}
```

Method : getTranslation()

```
public getTranslation(phrase:string):string {
    return this.data && this.data[phrase] ? this.data[phrase] : phrase;
}
```

Comment: Please use angularJs tag. Angular tag is for angular 2+ :-)

Comment: @alexKhymenko it is correctly tagged.. It is angular 2+ question

Comment: @Portekoi Sorry just the bindings in angular 2 are different. Assumed that it's angular.js.

Comment: Could you try `[attr.data-bv-notempty-message]="'The first name is required and cannot be empty' | i18n"`??

Comment: @PankajParkar no error but pipe is not running

Comment: @Portekoi Can You please give the link to the i18n pipe that You are using?

Comment: @alexKhymenko This one : https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n

Comment: Pipe have been implemented in SmartAdmin template. :-/

Comment: I've add the code @alexKhymenko

Comment: I'm accustomed to seeing that type of error when a pipe has not been imported into the parent module for a component. Try the simplest form of using the pipe: `<p>{{someString | i18n}}</p>`, where you define `someString` in your TypeScript.

If you get the same error, then it's likely a problem of the pipe not being imported. You could do this directly by listing it in the `declarations` section of the parent module

Comment: @JackKoppa No error when I use the pipe out of an input property.

Comment: @PankajParkar It's working now. Don't know why. I've stop and restart npm and your solution is running so reply to this question  and I'll mark it as the good reply. Thank you so much !

Comment: @Portekoi please check updated answer as well :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It throws an error because Angular didn't understand that attribute name. To allow custom attribute to work which are out of angular context, you could consider adding `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` element, which will any other custom attribute on HTML.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  exports: [ ... ],
  imports: [ ... ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

---

You could also use attribute binding like `[attr.something]="value"`

```
[attr.data-bv-notempty-message]="'The first name is required and cannot be empty' | i18n"
```